# How do I design a REST call that is just a data transformation?

Tags: api, rest, http

I am designing my first REST API.

Suppose I have a (SOAP) web service that takes MyData1 and returns MyData2.
It is a pure function with no side effects, for example:

```
MyData2 myData2 = transform(MyData myData);
```

transform() does not change the state of the server.  My question is, what REST call do I use?  MyData can be large, so I will need to put it in the body of the request, so POST seems required.  However, POST seems to be used only to change the server state and not return anything, which transform() is not doing.  So POST might not be correct?  Is there a specific REST technique to use for pure functions that take and return something, or should I just use POST, unload the response body, and not worry about it?

Answer (score 1):

I think POST is the way to go here, because of the sheer fact that you need to pass data in the body. The GET method is used when you need to retrieve information (in the form of an entity), identified by the Request-URI. In short, that means that when processing a GET request, a server is only required to examine the Request-URI and Host header field, and nothing else.

See the pertinent section of the [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.3) for details.

Comment: Thanks, I read it.  I think REST confuses me because it is about transfering resources (NOUNS) and I want a service to transform (VERBS) with a method-like approach.  Seems like an "impedance mismatch" to me but I am just going to go with POST and not think too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

[It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.”

It's not a great answer, but it's the right answer.  The real issue here is that HTTP, which is a protocol for the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s), isn't a great fit for document *transformation*.

If you imagine this idea on the web, how would it work?  well, you'd click of a bunch of links to get to some web form, and that web form would allow you to specify the source data (including perhaps attaching a file), and then submitting the form would send everything to the server, and you'd get the transformed representation back as the response.

But - because of the payload, you would end up using POST, which means that general purpose components wouldn't have the data available to tell them that the request was safe.

You could look into the WebDav specifications to see if [SEARCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5323#section-2) or [REPORT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3253#section-3.6) is a satisfactory fit -- every time I've looked into them for myself I've decided against using them (no, I don't want an HTTP file server).

Comment: Exactly the clarity I needed.  It is OK to hack transformation into the REST framework!